# Is there any Twitter API SDK for Android?

Tags: android, twitter, sdk

I tried https://github.com/sugree/twitter-android-sdk, but could not get it work....I am not even sure what CALLBACK_URI should I set to....I am working on a native android APP so very confused here.

I have used Facebook sdk and was able to update my status from my app successfully...now I try to do the same with twitter...why twitter does not even release an Android SDK ?

Comment: Can you review the answers again and check out my answer for Fabric (Which is the official SDK from Twitter) ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Far and away the best Twitter API for Android is [Twitter4J](http://twitter4j.org/).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on why?  Just trying to understand the alternatives--the easy way by asking.

Comment: here's a better option http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571352/is-there-any-twitter-api-sdk-for-android/28117939#28117939

Comment: As for as I understand, twitter4j are not supporting now. Last commit was a 1 year ago and today it miss much twitter functions.

Answer (score 8):

Twitter just release a bunch of new tools/sdk called [Fabric](https://fabric.io).

There is official Android SDK called [Twitter Kit](https://fabric.io/kits/android/twitterkit) which supports both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 6):

You could probably use [JTwitter](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php), a Twitter client library for Java.  See also http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/1089/

Comment: Thanks, I will try....I used Twitter4J and it works...just I need to prepare the twitter4j.properties file with hardcoded access_token.

Comment: I tried jtwitter....not as good as twitter4j....though its lib is 200k less than twitter4j.

Comment: Thanks Guido. in the second link; i can't find the class: twitter_info_activity.java: Do you know where i can get the file ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a lib that handles both Twitter and Facebook:
https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/

Answer (score 3):

Finally there's an official Twitter SDK https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android

From sdk description:
This Kit provides “Sign in with Twitter” functionality, an easy-to-use mechanism for making authenticated requests to Twitter’s REST API, ways to show Tweets within your apps, and phone number-based signin with Digits.

Answer (score 2):

might be this helps :
https://github.com/sugree/twitter-android-sdk

I found this fork really nice one..
https://github.com/glenwong/twitter-android-sdk

Wrapper around twitter4j

Answer (score 0):

I wrote one, complete with a login Activity and loading dialog, so it is very much "Android":

https://github.com/AndroidsOnSkateboards/AOSUtilsAndroid

Answer (score 0):

It's too late. But hope it helps . Check their [github](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-android/wiki/Getting-Started) repo.